# Сортировка на питоне без функций

Tags: python, сортировка

У меня проблема я хотел сделать сортировку на питоне без функций, но не выводит ответ. Помогите пожалуйста

первый код:

```
a = [123,26,1,2,23,21,13,55]
swap = 0
i = 0
index= 0
index1 = -1
min = a[i]
for i in range (len(a)):
    while True :
        if a[index] < min :
            swap = min
            min = a[index]
            a[index1] = min
            print('2')
        else :
            continue
        if len(a) == index :
            print(a)
            break
        index = index +1
```

вот мой 2 код:

```
a = [123,26,1,2,23,21,13,55]
swap = 0
i = 0
index1 = -1
min = a[i]
for i in range (len(a)):
    while True :
        if a[i] < min :
            swap = min
            min = a[i]
            a[index1] = min
            print('2')
        else :
            continue
        if len(a) == i :
            print(a)
            break
        index1 = index1 +1
```

Comment: не называйте свои переменные так же, как называются встроенные методы python. например, `min` - неприемлимое имя для переменной

Comment: уберите свои print(a) из цикла вообще и выводите на печать _после_ завершения цикла.

Comment: У вас что-то явно не то с переменной `swap` - она присваивается, но не используется.

Comment: А вообще сделайте лучше "пузырьковую сортировку". Там цикл в цикле и всё довольно просто и понятно. Её вполне можно и самостоятельно "изобрести", если не хотите подсматривать алгоритм.

Comment: Кстати, и условие `if len(a) == i` никогда не выполнится, даже если его вынести за окончание цикла - `i` никогда не присвоится верхняя граница `range` ни во время цикла, ни после выхода из него.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [123,26,1,2,23,21,13,55]

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
        if a[i] > a[j]:
           a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
print(a)  # [1, 2, 13, 21, 23, 26, 55, 123]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно примерно так:

```py
a = [123,26,1,2,23,21,13,55]
for _ in range(len(a)):
    for i in range(1, len(a)-j):
        if a[i] < a[i-1]:
            a[i], a[i-1] = a[i-1], a[i]

print(a)
```

или с досрочным выходом если за проход не было изменений:

```py
a = [123,26,1,2,23,21,13,55]
for _ in range(len(a)):
    c = 1 # флаг
    for i in range(1, len(a)-j):
        if a[i] < a[i-1]:
            a[i], a[i-1] = a[i-1], a[i]
            c = 0
    if c:
        break

print(a)
```